# Generate three non-overlapping mask for 2-D matrix that covers all of it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-d array and I want to divide it into 3 non-overlapping and random sub-matrix by mask generation. For example I have a matrix like follow:

```
input = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
```

I want three random zero-one masks like follow:

```
mask1 = [[0,1,0],
        [1,0,1],
        [0,0,0]]
mask2 = [[1,0,0],
         [0,1,0],
         [1,0,0]]
mask3 =[[0,0,1],
        [0,0,0],
        [0,1,1]]
```

But my input matrix is too large and I need to do it in a fast way. I also want to determine the ratio of ones for every mask as input. In the above example the ratio is equal for all masks.
To produce one random mask, I use following code:

```
np.random.choice([0, 1],size=(size of matrix[0],size of matrix[1]))
```

My problem is how to produce non-overlapping masks.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Submatrix or subarrays? Because if you mask like this you will get a 1-D array.

Comment: @Bartłomiej My problem is how to produce non-overlapping masks.

Comment: @Alex I need to produce a matrix or array with the same size as input (so-2d array) which contains one and zero.

Comment: I'm confused - posting a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help you get your question answered. In your case that involves making a sample matrix and an example of the output you are looking for.

Comment: @Alex I added a sample and hope that works.

Comment: Do you have any requirements on the distribution?  Do you need exactly 1/3rd (or as close as possible) of the array in each mask?

Comment: I should determine the distribution as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can make a random matrix of 0, 1, and 2, and then extract the m == 0, m == 1, and m == 2 values:

```
groups = np.random.randint(0, 3, (5,5))
masks = (groups[...,None] == np.arange(3)[None,:]).T
```

However, this wouldn't guarantee an equal number of elements in each mask.  To achieve that, you could permute a balanced allocation:

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)  # dummy input
groups = np.random.permutation(np.arange(a.size) % 3).reshape(a.shape)
masks = (groups[...,None] == np.arange(3)[None,:]).T
```

If you wanted a random probability to be in a group:

```
groups = np.random.choice([0,1,2], p=[0.3, 0.6, 0.1], size=a.shape)
```

or something.  All you need to do is decide how you want to assign cells to `groups`, and then you can build your masks.

For example:

```
In [431]: groups = np.random.permutation(np.arange(a.size) % 3).reshape(a.shape)

In [432]: groups
Out[432]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [433]: masks = (groups[...,None] == np.arange(3)[None,:]).T

In [434]: masks
Out[434]: 
array([[[False, False, False, False, False],
        [ True, False,  True, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True, False, False]]])
```

which gives me a full mask:

```
In [450]: masks.sum(axis=0)
Out[450]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

and reasonably balanced.  If the number of cells were a multiple of 3, these numbers would all agree.

```
In [451]: masks.sum(2).sum(1)
Out[451]: array([9, 8, 8])
```

You can use `.astype(int)` to convert from a bool array to an int array of 0s and 1s if you like.

Comment: Your idea is great, I am so so sorry that I forgot to note that I need to determine the ratio of ones in every mask.

Comment: I found out that there is problem when you compare groups and create masks. It only works when the number of rows and columns are equal.

Comment: @user137927: ah, that's easily changed.  Have to finish an errand first and then I'll update. :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, I found the solution, just said to inform and make the answer flawless, thanks :)